# C# MVC New Active Directory User, System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement.PrincipalOperationException: There is no such object on the server

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, active-directory

There are 5 or 6 similar threads, but none are solutions to this problem. It seems like when I try to create a new pricipal user for a NEW user account... it seems to be searching for that nonexistent account on the server. I'm posting all my code, with various versions of solutions found online that don't appear to work commented out (i.e. the last section and only uncommented section is the code that gets me the furthest in the process and produces this error)... I've been at this for 3 days:

```
public string AddADUser(string user_name, string password, string first_name, string last_name, string company_name) {

    /* string admin_userName = "SNEAKY/Administrator";
     string admin_password = "Password!";
     PrincipalContext ouContex = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain, "sneaky.com", admin_userName, admin_password, ContextType.Domain, "OU=Users,DC=Sneaky,DC=com");

     for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
         try {
             UserPrincipal up = new UserPrincipal(ouContex);
             up.SamAccountName = "Administrator" + i;
             up.SetPassword("Password!");
             up.Enabled = true;
             up.ExpirePasswordNow();
             up.Save();
             return "success";
         } catch (Exception ex) {
             return "FAILED:" + ex;
         }
     }

     return "success";*/
    /*string oGUID = string.Empty;
    string ldapPath = "LDAP://OU=USERS,DC=Sneaky,DC=com";
    try {
        string connectionPrefix = "LDAP://" + ldapPath;
        DirectoryEntry dirEntry = new DirectoryEntry(connectionPrefix);
        DirectoryEntry newUser = dirEntry.Children.Add
            ("CN=" + user_name, "user");
        newUser.Properties["samAccountName"].Value = user_name;
        newUser.CommitChanges();
        oGUID = newUser.Guid.ToString();

        newUser.Invoke("SetPassword", new object[] { password });
        newUser.CommitChanges();
        dirEntry.Close();
        newUser.Close();
    } catch (System.DirectoryServices.DirectoryServicesCOMException E) {
        //DoSomethingwith --> E.Message.ToString();

    }
    return oGUID;*/

    /*try {
        PrincipalContext ctx = new PrincipalContext(
                                 ContextType.Domain,
                                 "sneaky",
                                 "CN=Users,DC=sneaky,DC=com",
                                 "Administrator",
                                 "Password!");

        UserPrincipal usr = new UserPrincipal(ctx);

        usr.Name = "Jim Daly";
        usr.Description = "This is the user account for Jim Daly";
        usr.EmailAddress = "jimdaly@fabrikam.com";
        usr.SetPassword("securelyStoredPassword");
        usr.Save();

        usr.Dispose();
        ctx.Dispose();
        return "User Saved Sucessfully";
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        return "Error saving user: \n" + ex.ToString();
    }*/



    try {
        List<ADUser> ADUsers = new List<ADUser>();
        string admin_userName = "sneakyguy";
        string admin_password = "Password!";
        string domain = "sneaky";
        var context = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain, domain, "OU=Users,DC=Sneaky,DC=com", admin_userName, admin_password);


        UserPrincipal NewUserPrincipal = new UserPrincipal(context, user_name, password, true);

        NewUserPrincipal.UserPrincipalName = user_name;

        NewUserPrincipal.ExpirePasswordNow();
        //NewUserPrincipal.SamAccountName = user_name;
        // company NewUserPrincipal.GetUnderlyingObject.

        //NewUserPrincipal.GivenName = first_name;
        //NewUserPrincipal.Surname = last_name;
        //NewUserPrincipal.DisplayName = user_name;
        //NewUserPrincipal.Enabled = true;

        NewUserPrincipal.Save();
        return "User Saved Sucessfully";
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        return "Error saving user: \n" + ex.ToString();
    }
}
```

The code fails on this line (like its trying to ffind the user I'm trying to create???):

```
UserPrincipal NewUserPrincipal = new UserPrincipal(context, user_name, password, true);
```

Full Error Message:

```
System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement.PrincipalOperationException: There is no such object on the server. ---> System.DirectoryServices.DirectoryServicesCOMException: There is no such object on the server. at System.DirectoryServices.DirectoryEntry.Bind(Boolean throwIfFail) at System.DirectoryServices.DirectoryEntry.Bind() at System.DirectoryServices.DirectoryEntry.get_SchemaEntry() at System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement.ADStoreCtx.IsContainer(DirectoryEntry de) at System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement.ADStoreCtx..ctor(DirectoryEntry ctxBase, Boolean ownCtxBase, String username, String password, ContextOptions options) at System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement.PrincipalContext.CreateContextFromDirectoryEntry(DirectoryEntry entry) at System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement.PrincipalContext.DoLDAPDirectoryInit() --- End of inner exception stack trace --- at System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement.PrincipalContext.DoLDAPDirectoryInit() at System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement.PrincipalContext.DoDomainInit() at System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement.PrincipalContext.Initialize() at System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement.PrincipalContext.ContextForType(Type t) at System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement.Principal.GetStoreCtxToUse() at System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement.Principal.set_SamAccountName(String value) at System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement.UserPrincipal..ctor(PrincipalContext context, String samAccountName, String password, Boolean enabled) at SneakPM.Models.UserBAL.AddADUser(String user_name, String password, String first_name, String last_name, String company_name) in C:\Users\sneakyguy\Desktop\SneakyPM\SneakPM\Models\UserBAL.cs:line 162
```

Comment: Can you show which line throwing `PrincipalOperationException`? Seems that `PrincipalContext` usage should be examined.

Comment: Updated Information. I feel like I've tried every combination of every argument.